# How to get my BCC from Blockchain wallet

Tags: blockchain.info

I've wallet provided by [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/). As they wrote, they will not support BCC. My question is: How do I get safely BCC when I have BTC in my blockchain wallet?

Ty